# como comparar dos fechas en vb.net, para verificar su vencimiento

Tags: vb.net

Tengo que compara las fechas que estan vencidas, que significa esto, por ejemplo:
Si hoy es 06/04/2021 y la fecha de vencimiento es 01/04/2021, esto significa que esta vencida.
Si hoy es 30/03/2021 y la fecha de vencimiento es 06/04/2021, esto significa que no esta vencida.
en el codigo tengo today(que es la fecha actual) y fechavencimiento, como seria a modo de codigo?
Ayuda

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim FechaComparar = "10/7/2021"
Dim FechaActual = "19/7/2021"
Dim Diferencia = Date.Parse(FechaComparar).CompareTo(FechaActual)
If Diferencia > 0 then
Msgbox("Tiene vigencia")
else
Msgbox("Esta Vencido")
End If
```

El método **CompareTo** devuelve un numero, si ese numero es mayor que 0 entonces la fecha que se compara todavía no a pasado, pero si es menor entonces la fecha que se compara ya paso.

Answer (score 0):

```
' Puedes comparar-las directamente así 
Dim FechaToday As Date = "30/03/2021" ' Aquí puedes usar Now()
Dim FechaVencimiento As Date = "06/04/2021"

If FechaToday < FechaVencimiento Then
    MsgBox("Fecha No Vencida")
Else
    MsgBox("Fecha Vencida")
End If

' Si no usa DateDiff de VB. 
' Ejemplo:

Dim FechaComparar As Date = "10/7/2021"
Dim FechaActual As Date = "19/7/2021"
Dim Dias as Integer = DateDiff(DateInterval.Day, FechaComparar, FechaActual, FirstDayOfWeek.Monday, FirstWeekOfYear.Jan1)
Msgbox(Dias)
```

Answer (score -1):

Creo que esto te puede servir:

```
Dim resultado As Integer = DateTime.Compare(fecha1, fecha2)
```